# Postfix put incoming mails dependent on sender domain to a local catchall mailbox

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to configure postfix to put incoming mails from different domains to respective catchall mailboxes.

Use case is the following:

- enterprise customers send emails to the address 123@myservice.com (local part is always different, the domain part is always the same for all customers)
- the destination mailbox, where the mail is placed must be equal to the sender domain (emails from foo@customer1.com and bar@customer1.com are placed in the /customer1.com , mails from baz@customer2.com in /customer2.com)
- the mailboxes /customer1.com and /customer2.com are polled via POP3 by different clients with different authentication credentials

Example, the following incoming mail:

```
From: foo@customer1.com
To: 123@myservice.com
```

should be placed in the local virtual mailbox:

```
/customer1.com
```

The To-domain is always the same. The local mailboxes are all named as possible incoming From-domains.

Is there a possibility to use virtual_mailbox_maps or similar for this purpose?

**UPDATE:**

I have created following entry in `/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps`:

```
@myservice.com       catchall
```

to point all mails to the mailbox "catchall".

In this mailbox i have created a Sieve script  `/var/mail/vhosts/myservice.com/catchall/.dovecot.sieve`:

```
require ["variables"];

# pick any ("*") domain in From or Sender header
if address :matches :domain ["From", "Sender"] "*" {
        #  the variable ${1} contains the domain name
        redirect "${1}";
}
```

This Sieve script redirects all mails to the mailbox equals to sender domain (e.g.  customer1.com).

To reject all mails from not known (not in the database) domains, used smtpd_sender_restrictions in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =  permit_mynetworks, pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql_check_sender_access.cf
```

`/etc/postfix/pgsql_check_sender_access.cf`:

```
user = dbuser
password = dbpass
dbname = customers
query = select case count(*) when 0 then 'REJECT' else 'OK' end from servers where user_domain='%d';
hosts = 127.0.0.1:5432
```

Comment: Oh, you updated the question. I will take a further look when time permits...

Comment: i have updated, in the same time, you have answered, so i did not noticed it first. your answer make sence and i'm tring to implement your suggestion with Dovecot ( Pigeonhole, Sieve filtering rule). I will report my success (or fail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the MTA's job. It is better to do this in the MUA (your client program).

If you really want to do this on the server side choose some mail filtering program like dovecot (it is sieve compatible) or maildrop (has its own proprietary filtering solution).
(procmail is also available, but I would not recommend that one).

There is a howto for Maildrop configuration http://www.postfix.org/MAILDROP_README.html
How to set up filters: http://www.courier-mta.org/maildropex.html